# RubyMotion error : Objective-C stub for message 'open' type `c@:' not precompiled

Tags: ios, rubymotion

My code is throwing an error.

> *Objective-C stub for message 'open' type `c@:' not precompiled. Make sure you properly link with the framework or library that defines this
>   message.*

Comment: Class variables seem to work fine for me. I'd look for an `open` method being called, as that's what the error is mentioning.

Comment: It was to do with the cocoapods gem. Updated my question to make it more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of cocoapods 0.5.0. Updating to cocoapods 0.6.0.rc1 helped (0.6.0.rc2 does not work either)